# Query an oracle DB from Excel 2007

Tags: oracle, excel

I have 2 columns(Column A & Column B) and multiple rows in the excel.  I need to access the Oracle DB via excel.  Query is "Select Column1 from table where column2=column A in the sheet" and then I need to compare the Column B from excel and Column1 from table and put the difference in the third column.  How will I query the Oracle DB with the Column A in the where Class from Excel?  Please let me know.  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend:

http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/microsoft-excel/how-to-query-oracle-from-excel-2007/

The "magic" word is OLE DB